# TensorFlow Crashing - Aborted (core dumped)

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, tensorflow

I am getting the following error in TensorFlow:

```
2017-06-27 03:10:50.310215: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:893] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2017-06-27 03:10:50.310485: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:940] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: GeForce GTX 1060 6GB
major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate (GHz) 1.7715
pciBusID 0000:01:00.0
Total memory: 5.92GiB
Free memory: 5.43GiB
2017-06-27 03:10:50.310498: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:961] DMA: 0 
2017-06-27 03:10:50.310502: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:971] 0:   Y 
2017-06-27 03:10:50.310510: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1030] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:0) -> (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1060 6GB, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0)
2017-06-27 03:10:50.804537: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_def_util.cc:332] Op BatchNormWithGlobalNormalization is deprecated. It will cease to work in GraphDef version 9. Use tf.nn.batch_normalization().
2017-06-27 03:11:04.026835: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:352] Loaded runtime CuDNN library: 6021 (compatibility version 6000) but source was compiled with 5110 (compatibility version 5100).  If using a binary install, upgrade your CuDNN library to match.  If building from sources, make sure the library loaded at runtime matches a compatible version specified during compile configuration.
2017-06-27 03:11:04.027028: F tensorflow/core/kernels/conv_ops.cc:671] Check failed: stream->parent()->GetConvolveAlgorithms(&algorithms) 
Aborted (core dumped)
```

This is my console output after running an example neural network. Any Ideas? Is it a version mismatch and if so how can I fix it? I am almost certain that I have the latest versions of both cuDNN and CUDA toolkit. Any help is much appreciated :)

Comment: Just read the error. Having the latest versions of everything does not magically make everything compatible with each other. But building it from source should work (as mentioned in your output too). (Also have a look [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/8828))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tensorflow was compiled to work with version `5.1` of cuDNN but you are giving it version `6`. In general, changes of major version numbers also come with API changes.

You'll need to use the version of cuDNN which tensorflow expects, `5.1`.